# Windows Azure - Mobile services, database connection

Tags: azure-mobile-services, ssms, multiple-databases

I'm having trouble running sql commands to my database on Windows Azure. Previously I had no problems at all running my commands and stored procedures with SQL management studio until I added another database on the same server. I can still connect and even se all the tables and both databases i SQL management studio but I cannot run any commands.

If I use the online management portal I am able to run my SQL but not with SQL management studio.

```
select * from nextlabel.[Article]
```

and it gives the folowing error:

```
Invalid object name 'nextlabel.Article'.
```

Any ideas on how to connect properly to one of the databases or if I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: Did you try selecting your database first: `use <db name>; select * from nextlabel.Article`?

Comment: I can't use the "USE" statement. When I do I get an error message. Currently I managed to run regular SQL-commands by right clicking the DB and select "New query" (in SQL Server Management Studio). However, I still haven't quite figured out how to make stored procedures since I can't use the "USE" statement. So I'm like half way there now.